# Getting error after click on the the send button also not getting accesstoken and refreh token

Tags: docusignapi, stack-overflow, docusignconnect, docusignapextoolkit

getting bad request error
{
"error": "invalid_grant"
}It shows something like these
one click of the send button shows access and refresh token i want these

Comment: Hard to answer without more information. Are you doing this from postman? do you have any code written? what are you doing exactly, share your code, explain step by step. Very hard to answer without more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Auth Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/) with [Postman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LmiQ8zVJ1Co), you'll need the following

- Integration Key (ClientId)
- Secret Key (clientSecret)
- redirectURI

These must be configured on the [App and Keys page](https://admindemo.docusign.com/authenticate?goTo=appsAndKeys&_gl=1*1mgfn8l*_ga*MTA4NzkwNDY4NS4xNjcyNzczMjMz*_ga_1TZ7S9D6BQ*MTY3Nzk1MDkxNC4xMjcuMS4xNjc3OTUxMTI2LjU1LjAuMA..&_ga=2.194467941.979643548.1677528427-1087904685.1672773233&_gac=1.94093679.1676407332.CjwKCAiA_6yfBhBNEiwAkmXy51B4hoxWSqrbIDHICWtRqaO3D9VdU6uQWdzlXqKmXjzr6bZLTPn_kxoC2UQQAvD_BwE) correctly

Then there are two calls you need to make, one is done via a web browser where you need to log in to DocuSign (unless already logged on) and where you will provide consent.

That first call gives you a token, which you exchange for an access token in the second call, which is this one:

```
POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token?code={Code}&grant_type=authorization_code
```

**Note the code you got in the browser must be here in the request**

One of the headers for this call is called "Authorization" and should have the word "Basic " and then the two values (IK and Secret) encoded together:

For example, if your integration key is
7c2b8d7e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cda8a50dd73f
and the secret key is
d7014634-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-6842b7aa8861
you can get the base64 value in a JavaScript console with the following method call:

```
btoa('7c2b8d7e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cda8a50dd73f:d7014634-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-6842b7aa8861')
```